# Firefox - jQuery SlideDown/SlideUp

Tags: jquery, firefox

I am having an issue with the jQuery SlideDown/SlideUp.  When my div slides down, it pushes all other element below down.  But when it slides up on the span tags go back to their original location.

Has anyone found the solution to this?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you show us the code in question? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Make the style attribute of the div that your expanding to style="position:absolute"